# PostgreSQL 9.5 - update doesn't work when merging NULL with JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

My `users` table contains a `metadata` column of type `json`.
Now, I want to add new metadata to a user while preserving existing values.
So I'm using the `||` operator to merge 2 JSON objects:

```
UPDATE users
SET metadata = metadata::jsonb || '{"test": true}'::jsonb
WHERE id=...
RETURNING *;
```

Everything works fine when there are already some existing metadata.
However, when the previous value is `NULL` then the update doesn't work. The `metadata` after update is still `NULL`.

How can I improve my query so that it sets the new JSON object when the previous value is `NULL` or merges the previous and new values otherwise?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add coalesce:

```
UPDATE users
SET metadata = coalesce(metadata::jsonb,'{}'::jsonb) || '{"test": true}'::jsonb
WHERE id=...
RETURNING *;
```

it works similar like with normal strings `NULL || something` is always NULL

Comment: Wow! It helped. Thank you so much!

Comment: The coalesce part gets even simpler: `coalesce(metadata, '{}')::jsonb`